# Firebase static hosting with a simple contact form

Tags: firebase, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-hosting

I want to host a website in firebase with a simple contact form.

1. how it is possible using any of the technology-Ajax/AngularJS
2. how to connect static website data with firebase storage?
3. Can we directly add a contact form details to the firebase storage and retrive it ?

Comment: [Firebase Database](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/) <> [Firebase Storage](https://firebase.google.com/docs/storage/). Aside from that, you'll need to write your own HTML form and then use the [Firebase SDK/API](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/web/start) to store the data in the database. Showing these steps is a bit beyond the scope of Stack Overflow, but if you have problems with a specific step, provide an [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and we'll be glad to help.

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen thanks for your reply..so it is possible to save my form data to firebase database from my static website?

Comment: can i make any Ajax call to store these data to a different server and DB

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen what are the supported types in firebase tatic hosting? only html? or can i host a angular js app ?

Comment: Firebase Hosting can serve "any" file type. It just won't interpret anything in the file on the Firebase servers, which is why it's called "static" hosting. An Angular app **is** static, none of the JavaScript code is interpreted on the server. So it indeed *can* be hosted on Firebase.

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen so can i fetch the content form the server using ajax?

Comment: @Sibinfrancis Kindly let me know how you tacked this problem. I am also trying to use contact us form to get email from visitor on particular email using Firebase static hosting. Any details would be highly appreciated.